# Creating a new file, filename contains loop variable, python

Tags: python, file

I want to run a function over a loop and I want to store the outputs in different files, such that the filename contains the loop variable. Here is an example

```
for i in xrange(10):
   f = open("file_i.dat",'w')
   f.write(str(func(i))
   f.close()
```

How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simply construct the file name with `+` and `str`. If you want, you can also use [old-style](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) or [new-style formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to do so, so the file name can be constructed as:

```
"file_" + str(i) + ".dat"
"file_%s.dat" % i
"file_{}.dat".format(i)
```

Note that your current version does not specify an encoding ([you should](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)), and does not correctly close the file in error cases (a `with` statement [does that](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)):

```
import io
for i in xrange(10):
   with io.open("file_" + str(i) + ".dat", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(str(func(i))
```

Answer (score 4):

Concatenate the `i` variable to a string as follows:

```
f = open("file_"+str(i)+".dat","w")
```

OR

```
f = open("file_"+`i`+".dat","w") # (`i`) - These are backticks, not the quotes.
```

See [here](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) for other techniques available.

Comment: Apologies, it's been edited - I downvoted when the second example had quotes where it now has backticks

Answer (score 4):

Use `f = open("file_{0}.dat".format(i),'w')`.  Actually, you might want to use something like `f = open("file_{0:02d}.dat".format(i),'w')`, which will zero-pad the name to keep it at two digits (so you get "file_01" instead of "file_1", which can be nice for sorting later).  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for i in xrange(10):
   with open('file_{0}.dat'.format(i),'w') as f:
       f.write(str(func(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use f-strings

- This is the simplest and most recent implementation of string formatting.
- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- The string is preceded by an `f` and the variable is inside the string quotes, surrounded by `{}`.

  - `f"file_{i}.dat"`
- [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

  - The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.
- For python 3, this use `range` not `xrange`
- `f.write(f'{func(i)}')` or `f.write(str(func(i)))`

```py
def func(i):
    return i**2

for i in range(10):
    with open(f"file_{i}.dat", 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'{func(i)}')
```