# Verilog filename using for loop variable

Tags: string, for-loop, verilog

My question is similar to the following question.
[Creating a new file, filename contains loop variable, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560600/creating-a-new-file-filename-contains-loop-variable-python)

Depending the value of `NUM_PU`, I want to define my output filenames as

```
serial_pu0.out
serial_pu1.out
... etc
```

The following code doesn't work since the simulator treats the characters inside quotes (`""`) as strings.  Any suggestions?

```
integer file [0:NUM_PU-1];
generate
    for(i=0;i<NUM_PU;i=i+1) begin : serial_data_gen
        initial begin
            file[i] = $fopen ("serial_pu[i].out", "w");
        end
        always@(posedge i_Clk) begin
            if(serial_wr[i]) begin
                $fwrite (file[i], "%c", serial_data_2d[i]);
                $write("%c",serial_data_2d[i]);
            end
        end
    end
endgenerate
```

Comment: Haven't tested this myself, but looks like there might be an answer for you here: http://www.fpgarelated.com/usenet/fpga/show/15972-2.php

Answer (score 0):

You can compose the filename dynamically using `$sformatf`.

```
initial begin
    file[i] = $fopen($sformatf("serial_pu%0d.out", i), "w");
end
```

This will create filenames:

- serial_pu0.out
- serial_pu1.out
- ...

Comment: thanks for you response. $sformatf doesn't seem to work for Verilog. Looks like its supported only in System Verilog.

Comment: True, it's only in the SV standard, though some simulators may support it for Verilog. You may also want to try `$psprintf` which works the same way and some simulators may support.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically construct a file name string using `$sformat` in Verilog (IEEE Std 1364):

```
module tb;

parameter NUM_PU=2;

integer file [0:NUM_PU-1];
genvar i;
reg [999:0] filename;

generate
    for(i=0;i<NUM_PU;i=i+1) begin : serial_data_gen
        initial begin
            $sformat(filename, "serial_pu%0d.out", i);
            file[i] = $fopen(filename, "w");
        end
    end
endgenerate

endmodule
```