# Is there a verilog function to iterate over multiple input files for validation?

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I can open a file with

```
integer fd;
fd = $fopen ("file_to_open.txt", "r");
```

But if i have multiple files in a directory such as

```
f1.txt
f2.txt
f3.txt
```

**How can I iterate over these files without explicitly defining their name in my verilog testbench?**

In bash, this would be done with:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
    ...
done
```

Comment: If the file names follow a simple pattern like that (`f*.txt`), then [this should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713326/verilog-filename-using-for-loop-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog does not have a way of directly interacting with the Operating System a simulation is running on, so it cannot expand file names.

Two alternatives you have in Verilog are:

1. writing some C code that does this and linking that code through the VPI (difficult)
2. Creating a bash script that builds your list of files into a text file, then reading that list one line at a time with `$fgets` or `$fscanf`. (cumbersome)

This would be much easier if you were using SystemVerilog because it has string data types, and a direct interface to C (DPI)