# How can I use `while` to create 10 `.txt` files In the path (on my desktop)?

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python. 
I want to know how to write a script for creating files that uses `while` to create 10 files in a given path (I want the name of the first file `1.txt` and `2.txt` to `10.txt` for the rest).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please start with reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Why not `for`, a slightly more logical choice?

Comment: Probably because it's an assignment in a programming class where the students first learn how to do a loop manually before then being taught that there is something that does the counting and condition checking `for` you...

Comment: Then the assignment failed, `for` there is always someone who answers `while` such an assignment was designed to make the student learn something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new file, filename contains loop variable, python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560600/creating-a-new-file-filename-contains-loop-variable-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using while loops, a solution could look like this:

```
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    with open("{}.txt".format(i), "w") as handle:
        handle.write("Some content ...")
    i += 1
```

However, using a for loop is much more appropriate in this case:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    with open("{}.txt".format(i), "w") as handle:
        handle.write("Some content ...")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os


def create_files(path, n):
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        with open(os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.txt'), 'w+') as f:
            f.write('content')
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_files('/tmp/test', 10)
```

use while to loop, open(path, 'w+') to create file.

I'm new to Python too, hope it helps, have fun.