# Using items in list to create file name - for loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop

- I have a list that I am using for a for-loop.
- Each item in the list has an action carried out, but I want to write a file for what has happened.
- How can I use the variable in the for loop to create specific file names for each item in the list?

```py
mylist = ['hello', 'there', 'world']
for i in mylist:
    outputfile = open('%i.csv', 'a')
    print('hello there moon', file=outputfile)
```

- Am I on the right track using `%i` to represent individual items in the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a new file, filename contains loop variable, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560600/creating-a-new-file-filename-contains-loop-variable-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=format%20mini#format-specification-mini-language) to do what you need as follows:

```
mylist = ['hello', 'there', 'world']

for word in mylist:
    with open('{}.csv'.format(word), 'a') as f_output:
        print('hello there moon', file=f_output)
```

Using `with` will also automatically close your file afterwards.

`format()` has many possible features to allow all kinds of string formatting, but the simple case is to replace a `{}` with an argument, in your case a `word`.

Answer (score 3):

Use following code.

```
mylist = ['hello', 'there', 'world']
for i in mylist:
    outputfile = open('%s.csv'%i, 'a')
    print('hello there moon', file=outputfile)
    outputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `%s` since the items in the list are strings.

```
outputfile = open('%s.csv' % i, 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['hello', 'there', 'world']
for item in mylist:
   with open('%s.txt'%item,'a') as in_file:
      in_file.write('hello there moon')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use f-strings

- This is the simplest and most recent implementation of string formatting.
- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- [PEP 498 - Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- The string is preceded by an `f` and the variable is inside the string quotes, surrounded by `{}`.

  - `f'{i}.csv'`
- [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

  - The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.

#### Using code from OP

```py
mylist = ['hello', 'there', 'world']
for i in mylist:

    # open the file
    outputfile = open(f'{i}.csv', 'a')

    # write to the file
    print('hello there moon', file=outputfile)

    # close the file
    outputfile.close()
```

#### Close the file using `with`

```py
mylist = ['hello', 'there', 'world']
for i in mylist:

    with open(f'{i}.csv', 'a') as outputfile:

        outputfile.write('hello there moon')
```